# SSMS debug failure: Failed to process configuration file

Tags: sql-server

I executed my SQL Server Management Studios debugger and ran into this unexpected error.
["Failed to process configuration file"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV02t.png)

Still encountered the failure after restarting via task manager.

i went to repair my SQL Server through programs and features
["Release repair and uninstall"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX1HA.png)

after restarting my server i still received the same "Failed to process configuration file" error.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does it also occur when SSMS is run as administrator?

Comment: @Bouke Even when running as an administrator i still receive the same message. Still, thanks, i forgot to set my properties and you reminded me.

Comment: Can you connect to the database using other tools, for instance Visual Studio?

Comment: I can still connect to databases with or without visual studio, only thing I cannot do is debug my query.

Comment: Mmm, I ran out of options...

Comment: Its cool dude, somebody might come along. I do appreciate the quick response.